# Is there any way to set ir.cron user is current odoo logged in user in odoo12?

Tags: python-3.x, cron, scheduler, odoo-12, odoo-13

I want to set **ir.cron** job but by default it is getting **Odoobot** as a user but I want to set **logged in** User as a ir.cron job user by default.

Because each user has his own token, so, while running scheduler, it gets **none** instead of token because the scheduler user is Odoobot.

Note:

> As we can change user from scheduler in technical setting, in this
>   case the other user also get the token of scheduler user. or we can
>   create scheduler for each user separately. is there any way to handle
>   this in a single scheduler.

I want just create a generic scheduler which work for each user.

```
<record id="office365_cron_do_tasts_import" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Auto Office365 tasks import</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_sync_office365"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="active">0</field>
        <field name="code">model.auto_import_tasks()</field>
        <field name='interval_number'>5</field>
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name='interval_type'>minutes</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: What if you have Three logged user in the same time, do you randomly chose one?

Comment: then , what i have to do to handle this issue?
should i create  separate scheduler for each user?

Comment: This ir.cron should run for all users ? Or only current logged users ? Means if you have 3 logged user this cron should run three time each time it's executed by one of them,  or if you have 100 users even if they are not logged at this moment should we run it 100 time, you need to explain more and put the code of the method if it's possible and explain what it does lay be we can give you a better idea, and when this cron should be executed ?